# How to derive the equation of a density distribution in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am using the following procedure to get the density plot of transaction counts:

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA = Tran_Restaurant ;
  density Transaction_Count/ scale=density ;
  "Restaurant Transaction Count";
  XAXIS LABEL = 'Transaction_Count' GRID VALUES = (0 TO 100 BY 10);
RUN;
```

Sample Data:

```
Customer_ID   Transaction_Count
1213x         23
2131x         14
```

Customer_ID is distinct in the data set.
So, from the plot for each transaction_count we can get the number of customers.

I wanted to get the equation of the density curve? Is it possible to do that in SAS?

Comment: Take a look at PROC UNIVARIATE and/or PROC KDE. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/07/27/visualize-kernel-density-estimate.html

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your data is normal, you can estimate the distribution using `PROC UNIVARIATE`

```
proc univariate data=Tran_Restaurant;
    var Transaction_Count;
    histogram Transaction_Count / normal;
run;
```

Scroll down to the section labeled `Fitted Normal Distribution` for the estimates of mu and theta.

If you have SAS/ETS and your data is not normally distributed, you can try to estimate it using [`PROC SEVERITY`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/68148/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_severity_overview.htm). If you have a machine with lots of cores, use `PROC HPSEVERITY` instead (it'll run much faster).  Out of the box, this proc can fit various predefined distributions to a set of data and estimate what their parameters are. You can optionally include your own custom distributions, which makes it extremely powerful.

I personally like to estimate how close a distribution fits using the KS statistic, but there are a variety of other ways to choose your distribution depending on the goal.

```
ods graphics on;

proc severity data=Tran_Restaurant
              outest=myests
              criteria=KS
              ;
    dist _ALL_;
    loss transaction_count;
run;
```

It will return a set of possible predefined distributions and their closest fit.
By default, `PROC SEVERITY` will fit:

- Burr
- Exponential
- Gamma
- Generalized Pareto Distribution
- Inverse Gaussian
- Lognormal
- Pareto
- Scaled Tweedie
- Tweedie
- Weibull

Answer (score 1):

That statement is estimating a normal density curve to your discrete data.  A normal density has 2 parameters, mean and standard deviation.  You can get that from `PROC MEANS`.

```
proc means data=Tran_Restaurant mean std;
var Transaction_Count;
run;
```

Now you have an issue of discrete count values and a continuous distribution.  Multiple ways of doing this, none is perfect.

One way is to get the probability of being in a range around a given number. Because your numbers are integers, you could use a +/- 0.5.  Put another way

```
P(x | V-0.5 <= x <= V+0.5)
```

For a normal distribution using the SAS CDF function:

```
P = CDF('normal',V+.5,mean,std) - CDF('normal',V-.5,mean,std)
```

So if your data has 100 observations, then you would expect

```
E_count = P*100;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes a lot of sense. Had a question on it though.

P(x | V-0.5 <= x <= V+0.5):
Over here by V you mean each integer, right? So we are trying to find the probability with 1 as bin size?
And in the end we are multiplying it by 100 to get the count for each bin?

Comment: Correct, V is the integer you are looking for.  You get a probability.  So if your sample is 100, then you would multiple the sample size by the probability to get the expected number.  If the sample size was 123, then it would be `E_count = P*123;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ODS OUTPUT` to get the specific data points into a dataset; like so:

```
ods output sgplot=datapoints;
proc sgplot ... ;
run;
ods output close;
```

It won't give you the equation, however.  The equation is given in the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/62603/HTML/default/viewer.htm#density-stmt.htm); you'd just have to calculate the parameters in `PROC MEANS` or somewhere else, I suppose.  I don't know of a way to get SGPLOT to give you them directly.

Comment: More to it than this.  He's looking to use a continuous distribution to estimate discrete data.  He can get a probability of being between 2 values, but not the count of customers from his sample.

Comment: @DomPazz sure, that's what the second paragraph is about, right?  The equation for the density function is defined in the documentation,  he just needs the parameters, which is available in PROC MEANS.